# Is the Spanish word for "academy" pronounced the same as it is for "academia?"

Tags: pronunciación

I was recently making a recording that included the word "academy," and wanting to be certain of where the stress was placed in that word, I looked it up.  The sources I used indicated that it is spelled the same for both "academy" and "academia" and gives this spelling:

**academia**

Previously, I had thought "academy" stressed the "i" in the Spanish word and "academia" stressed the "e."  I would feel more comfortable using this word if a native or fluent speaker could confirm this for me.

Comment: After posting this, I remembered I have a hard copy of a Spanish dictionary and looked this word up in it.  It contains an entry for "**academe, academia**" and then gives "**mundo académico**" for it.  To specify "academia" must one always say "**mundo académico**?"

Comment: The stress is always on the "e". For the stress to be on the "i", the word would have to be spelled "academ**í**a" to break the diphthong. There is no such spelling in Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding phonetics for *academia* is /ˌækəˈdiːmɪə/, the stress is the same when considering *academia = akaˈðemja* in Spanish. The stress is placed the third syllable. (Of course, by not extending the vowel *i.*)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick reply, Ustanak.  My question, however, wasn't so much about where the stress is placed for "**academia**" in general.  I wanted to know if the word is stressed in the same way whether referring to an "**academy**" or "**academia**."  In English, though these two words are very related, they have very distinctive meanings.  Is this not also true in Spanish, and if so, isn't one pronounced slightly differently the other?

Comment: @LisaBeck Check my edited answer. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Also, for anyone who doesn't read phonetic transcriptions all that well, here's a link to some sound recordings of it: http://forvo.com/word/academia/#es.  Notice that the definition given (upper right corner) is simply "academy."  I suppose that answers my question by itself, but I was wondering if "academy" is ever pronounced "a-cad-e-MI-a."

Comment: So, definitively, it is the same for both.  No exceptions.  And you just distinguish the two through context.  Correct?

Comment: @LisaBeck Yes, the stress is the same.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know.  ¡Gracias!

Comment: No, "academia" (sp) means almost exclusively "academy" (en). To say "academia" (en) you must say "mundo académico", "círculo académico", "ámbito académico", "comunidad académica", etc, where "académico/a" can be replaced with "universitario/a" depending on the context.

Comment: @Yay Of course, it depends of the context; *academia* (en) is not my option for me to use, though.